# Recreating a table from MS Word (with a mix of rotated and non-rotated text)

Tags: tables

I have the following table which is created in MS Word:

[image]

I want to recreate it in LaTeX as it is (keeping the same rotation of column headers) and I must keep the vertical and horizontal lines as it is.

Any "cosmetic" changes to make the first column appear "nicer" would be good too.

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem very right.

```
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}



    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | c | c | c | c|c|c|c| >{\centering\arraybackslash} c|}
      \hline
    Description (all named investigators on any proposal or grant/project/fellowship in which a participant is involved, project title, source of support, scheme and round) &  \rot{Same Research Area (Yes/No)}  & \rot{Support Status (Requested/Current/Past)} & \rot{Proposal/Project ID} & \rot{2013 (\$'000)} & \rot{2014 (\$'000)} & \rot{2015 (\$'000)} & \rot{2016 (\$'000)} & \rot{2017 (\$'000)} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Investigators:}
    In
    \textbf{Project Title:} 
    Identifying Challenges and
    Opportunities in Socially Responsible Investments
    \textbf{Funding Body:} ARC
    \textbf{Fund Scheme Round:}
    DP15
     & Yes & Requested & DP150102407 &  &   & 186 & 196 & 192 
    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}




\end{document}
```

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Ok sure, I've tried a few things but didn't work out, I'll post my MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution where `\rotatebox` from `rotating` package  is used. `\newline` is used for line break in a cell.
Here the suggestion redefines the X column type to be of m type instead of default p:

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
```

and create two new column type M and C, of difference width, with horizontal and vertical centering:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating,array}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\newcommand\rot[2][90]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{#2}} %#2=90
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|M|M|M|C|C|C|C|C|}
      \hline
Description (all named investigators on any proposal or grant/project/fellowship in which a participant is involved, project title, source of support, scheme and round) &  \rot{Same Research Area\strut}\rot{(Yes/No)}  & \rot{Support Status} \rot{(Requested/Current/Past)} & \rot{Proposal/Project ID} & \rot{2013 (\$'000)} & \rot{2014 (\$'000)} & \rot{2015 (\$'000)} & \rot{2016 (\$'000)} & \rot{2017 (\$'000)} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Investigators:}
    In \newline
   \textbf{Project Title:} 
    Identifying Challenges and
    Opportunities in Socially Responsible Investments\newline
    \textbf{Funding Body:} ARC\newline
    \textbf{Fund Scheme Round:}\newline
    DP15
     & Yes & Requested & DP150102407 &  &   & 186 & 196 & 192 \\    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```